# Как сделать цикл или что то наподобие в notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Подскажите, есть к примеру код

```
<?php
$i=0;
$html = file_get_contents('https://site.ru/page/1');
...
?>
```

Как в notepad++ одним махом скопировать весь код к примеру 100 раз з заменой page/1 на цикл до page/100 ? Если это возможно, подскажите как.

Результат примерно такой:

```
<?php
$i=0;
$html = file_get_contents('https://site.ru/page/1');
...
?>

<?php
$i=0;
$html = file_get_contents('https://site.ru/page/2');
...
?>
```

---...---

```
<?php
$i=0;
$html = file_get_contents('https://site.ru/page/100');
...
?>
```

Comment: Можно, конечно, написать свой макрос... но в сотню раз быстрее скопировать эту хрень в Excel, там размножить с инкрементом, и вернуть обратно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак, потому что разрабы notepad++ не расчитывали на такой ход мыслей. А в чем проблема написать:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
for($j = 0; $j < 100; $j++)
{
    $html = file_get_contents('https://site.ru/page/'.$j);
    // ...
}
?>
```

а остальное просто удалить? )

Comment: у меня $i уже используется

Comment: <?php

$i=0;
$html = file_get_contents('https://site.ru/page/1');
preg_match_all( '#<div class="item">(.+?.)</div>#is', $html, $matches );    
foreach ( $matches[1] as $value ) {
    $i++;
    echo $value.'<br>';
    if($i == 10) break;
}
?>

Comment: Подправил с учетом вашего замечания )

Comment: спасибо, сработало!

Comment: Почувствуй силу цикла! Пожалуйста ))

Comment: можно еще один вопрос по теме? а как сделать цикл не по числам, а по всем символам например? если использовать к примеру первые 5 символов вместо чисел

Comment: Так? 
$string = "строка";
for ($i = 0, $i < strlen($string); $i++) 
{
   echo $string[$i];
}

Comment: "строка" что здесь должно быть?

Comment: "строка" это любая строка, по которой вы будете бегать в цикле. Скопируйте себе код и запустите, сразу все поймете