# как с помощью текстового редактора сделать find replace increment

Tags: текст, sublime-text, notepad++, replace, find

Есть тектовый файл, в нем среди прочего есть помеченые строки тремя иксами

```
xxx
```

как эти иксы заменить на численные значения с инкриментом

```
001
002...
```

Comment: например: `$ seq -f 'str%g' $(wc -l файл1 | cut -d' ' -f1) > файл2`

Comment: У меня для этого в SciTE написан скрипт на Lua, вызываемый по нажатию кнопки и изменяющий редактируемый текст.  Насколько я знаю, для встраивания своих скриптов в другие редакторы нужно писать сишный код, т.к. кастомизация редактора каким-либо скриптовым языком почти везде отсутствует.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать цикл или что то наподобие в notepad++?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/915249/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-notepad)